# jQuery move select option to the second position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have select :

```
<select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
...
<option value="37">Switzerland</option>
...
</select>
```

How can I move option with text `Switzerland` to the second position in the list ? Result will be :

```
 <select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="37">Switzerland</option>
<option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
...
</select>
```

Comment: why can you not do that in html?

Comment: I believe the list of country names is coming from JQuery. And this HTML is generated dynamically. If yes, can you please share the javascript logic which is doing this stuff?
I that is static content, you can do that in HTML.

Comment: Do you want to sort by value field

Comment: May be you are sorting by value logic sorts the values by numbers ( 37,40),

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jquery after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to *place* it after the *first-child* in the `select` - see demo below:

```js
$('select[name=country_id] option:first-child').after($('select[name=country_id] option[value=37]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="37">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @babboe2babboe2 let us know your thoughts on the answer(s), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the `<option>` elements, and then filter them by the `value` attribute. Finally, once you have the correct element selected (in this case for Switzerland), you can use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) to move its location in the DOM.

**Example:**

```js
var $opts = $('.selCommon').children();
$opts.filter('[value="37"]').insertBefore( $opts.eq(1) )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="40">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="40">USA</option>
  <option value="37">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var options = $('.selCommon option' );

      var SwitzerlandIndex=0;
      var cnt=0;

      $(options).each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Switzerland"){
          SwitzerlandIndex=cnt;
        }  
        cnt++;
      });

      $(options[SwitzerlandIndex]).insertAfter($(options[0]));
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="41">Test</option>
<option value="37">Switzerland</option>
<option value="38">Test 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on the value

```js
$('.selCommon option').sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value).appendTo('.selCommon');
$('.selCommon').val("")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selCommon" name="country_id">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="40">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="57">Sweden</option>
  <option value="37">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="12">USA</option>
</select>
```